# How to drain an iPhone battery?

Tags: iphone, battery, performance

My phone froze last night and the battery still has not died. My lock and home button don't work, so I can't just hold the power button down and reset it. I'm on a friend's computer, so my phone isn't linked or whatever to this computer. Is there any other way to get my phone to turn off faster, since I *need* it for tomorrow.

It has done this before, but I had music playing and wasn't fully charged, but this time I was on my browser with a fully charged phone.

This happened over 26 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have **Find My Phone** enabled on the device, you could try logging into [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) or using the [App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8) from any other iOS device. This way you could, firstly, know the exact battery level and, secondly, you could trigger the locating feature which will help with the battery drainage.